# Discord Bot: addRoles does not exist, but is listed in documentation to exist?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a small Discord bot for a server. When a user joins, it's meant to greet them and add two roles. Without the roles part, it works.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRoles says that the function exists.

I get this error:

````
at DiscordClient.bot.on (C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\bot.js:89:9)
    at DiscordClient.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emit (C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1580:14)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1904:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.ontext (C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:371:5)
    at C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (C:\Users\Dialg\Documents\coding\discord_bots\millybot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:347:3)```

addRole or strings do not work.


```// Message to new users
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    let guild = member.guild;

    bot.sendMessage({
        to: "620583787142578185",
        message: "Long message"
    });

    // Adds Nicknames + Reader to the user
    member.addRoles(['594831071376572417', '541669344497631233']).catch(ConsoleError);
});
````

Comment: does addRole work?

Comment: Are you using `master`?

Comment: Did you try it with strings? Like so: ``member.addRoles(['594831071376572417', '541669344497631233'])``

Comment: addRole and strings both didn't work. What is master?